# Using Silverlight 4 WebClient OpenReadCompleted throughs Security Exceptions on hosted web server. What's the pronblem?

Tags: silverlight, webserver

Seems to be a simple thing using a WebClient object to retrieve content of a text file in a Silverlight web application.

It works in our intranet setup on a local server, but when deployed on a hosted "hostgator" server, WebClient gets a security exception.  Following suggestions from numerous web blogs, I tried crossdomain access policy and crossdomain.xml with no result - no wonder, all in on the same domain.

```
    private void LoadCSVFile(string csvFile)
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(csvFile, UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = String.Format("Ex accessing csv: {0}\n{1}", csvFile,
```

}
        }

//the csvFile is an absolute path: http://myserver.com/myapplication:port/sourcefiles/file.csv
//The sourcefiles is a virtual directory in the same website containing csv files

```
    void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            try
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Result))
                {
                    mainFileData = new List<string>();
                    string line;
                                        }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMessage = ex.InnerException;
```

}else
{
"here is the place for the exception!!!!!!! so, e.Error is not null"
}
}

The text of the exception reads: System.SecurityException: Security error at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) etc.

Spend 2 days gooogling with no result.

Please help.
V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

(1) The format for the URL that you list (http://myserver.com/myapplication:port/sourcefiles/file.csv) looks odd.  Shouldn't it be http://myserver.com:port/myapplication/sourcefiles/file.csv?  Or is that just a typo?

(2) What's the port number that you're accessing?  The Silverlight WebClient will only access ports 80 and 443.

(3) Can you get to the file using a direct URL?  Sometimes web servers need to be told about a specific file type before they'll allow it to be served up.

Comment: Ken, thanks for your response:(1) the full url=myworks.com/$sitepreview/myworks.com:8091/sourcefiles/file1.csv. - yep, just a typo (2)on intranet i access files on port 8091 just fine. (3) here is something. How to in instruct server for the "cvs" file type to be served?

Comment: Ken, thank again, you gave me a hint and I just solved the problem.  I simply had to set the virtual directory to accept scripts - that was the cause of the security exception.  Cheers